# How do you move a conversation to the chat area?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

I've had occasions when someone replies to my question and I'd like to invite the person to the chat room for a few followups, instead of having a dozen comments going back and forth. How do you do this? It shows the option to move conversation to chat when the comments exceed a certain number; but I don't see the option before that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no such option available (I was looking for it recently with no luck)

According to [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

> 2011-06-10: When adding a new comment to a post with many comments
>   between two users in a short time, a link is provided to create a chat
>   room to continue the conversation.

'auto chat link' is relatively new feature.

However,  [Can I request a chat with someone who answered my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79202/can-i-request-a-chat-with-someone-who-answered-my-question) looks like alternative and top answer also indicates that chat link existed but was removed (if I understand it correctly)

Comment: +1 Also, if you don't have 100 rep to create your own chat room, feel free to use [our general SharePoint chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint).