# How do we invite a particular user to chat?

Tags: support, chat

A certain user was of particular help to me in one of my questions.  I would like to talk with him some more on the same topic.  Is there any way I can invite him into a chat room, or somehow communicate with him (if he is willing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you should be able to create your own chat room (having at least 100 rep) and invite this user there - in easiest case when you both are already in an other chat.

I tried to figure it out to give you a more detailed explanation, but I failed to log in.

[Here](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383/how-do-you-move-a-conversation-to-the-chat-area) you have a similiar question, offering some answer and link to a next question.

(I don't know why, but when I click here at top on "chat", it shows me I need to log in. After clicking there, it provides me the usual ways to log in. So I got logged in on main SE site, but returning to chat declines that I am logged in. Maybe it has to do that I deny a referrer while browsing.)

Comment: I've seen that problem with "needing" to log in before.  I find that if, in Firefox, I do a full refresh (skipping the browser cache) that it fixes the problem.

Comment: There was a link from the link that has a good answer, proposing to create the room, then in the comments of the main question, post the link and address the user you want to invite (at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79202/can-i-request-a-chat-with-someone-who-answered-my-question).

Comment: If you mention the user in a chat room, he will get a notification in the top left drop down